# Neo4j string or text data types

Tags: neo4j

Trying to work with strings.
Can't find any specs about this data types.
What is the max length os String in Neo4j?
If the limit is 256, is there a larger type, like Text?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4996/amount-of-data-per-node-in-neo4j

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Neo4j there's no distinction between a string and something like `TEXT`. Property values in Neo4j can be java primitive types (int, long, double, boolean, ...), Strings and arrays of those. Strings in java can have an arbitrary length, same applies for Neo4j.

Be aware that long strings get handled internally different, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/property-compression.html#_compressed_storage_of_short_strings. This does not impact the client behaviour but can impact on the performance.