# Neo4j property string limit

Tags: neo4j

I'm working on a KB type structure, and I'd like to store the free-form text / web content for each KB entry in a property. These can get pretty long - upwards of 60K or more text.

My question is:

- What is the limit for a string property?
- Can unstructured text like this be imported via CSV? By unstructured text I mean multiple lines, embedded quotes, HTTP tags, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217352/neo4j-string-or-text-data-types

Comment: It links to a page that doesn't exist any more. There's a comment on the DBA page which doesn't have a clear answer, and the Neo4j doc's page has a broken link to a java lang specification.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no size limit for a string. All long strings get externalized into a separate store file, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/property-compression.html for details.

This "strings store file" uses internally a block size. If your string is larger, multiple blocks will be allocated resulting in multiple seek and read operation on your disc. The block size can be configure **only** when creating a new data store using a unofficial config option `string_block_size`, see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.3/community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseSettings.java#L447.

Importing unstructured text from CSV should work if the strings in question are wrapped in double quotes (`"`) **and** any double quotes inside the string get doubled, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html#load-csv-import-data-containing-escaped-characters. I don't remember completely but I think newlines are handled correctly if they are inside a double quoted string.

Comment: This is slightly misleading. While there is no _hard limit_ for string properties. You can't index properties >8KB (32KB using legacy indices) which can be limiting for many use cases

Comment: @Downgoat That's only for the b-tree indexes, but Neo4j also has full-text-indexes: “Full-text indexes are powered by the Apache Lucene indexing and search library. A full-text index enables you to write queries that matches within the contents of indexed string properties.” https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.2/administration/indexes-for-full-text-search/

Comment: @Magne I am aware, I addressed that. Legacy or full-text indexes still have a limit of 32KB https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/index-limitations-and-workaround/#_key_size_limit

Comment: @Downgoat I think you are referring to `native-btree-1.0` (default, 8 KB) or `lucene+native-3.0` (legacy/deprecated, 32 KB), but I don’t see the same limitation for the aptly named `fulltext-1.0`.

Comment: Afaik, Apache Lucene doesn't seem to have a hard limit on the text it is able to index. Might be a bit outdated, but: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Text-field-indexing-limit-in-Lucene